# Permission Denied for create_template_postgis-1.5.sh - Django

Tags: python, django

```
$ wget https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_downloads/create_template_postgis-1.5.sh
$ chmod +x create_template_postgis-1.5.sh

tameen@tameen-HP:~/Downloads/ $ sudo -u postgres ./create_template_postgis-1.5.sh
sudo: unable to execute ./create_template_postgis-1.5.sh: Permission denied
```

Login as Root

```
 root@tameen-HP:~/Downloads/ $ sudo -u postgres ./create_template_postgis-1.5.sh
    sudo: unable to execute ./create_template_postgis-1.5.sh: Permission denied
```

Why Permission denied?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's denied is because you are executing the whole stuff as a superuser privileges using an account that isn't a superuser in this case **postgres**.

All you have to do is to copy the create_template_postgis-1.5.sh on your /home/

```
 cp create_template_postgis-1.5.sh /home/
```

Then do a `su - postgres` to login to the postgres user or as a postgres user.

Navigate to /home/ and then execute the following command

```
./create_template_postgis-1.5.sh
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/create_template_postgis-1.5.sh’: Permission denied

Comment: login first as a root then make sure you do something like this after copying to /home/

`cd /home
chown postgres create_template_postgis-1.5.sh`

then you're good to go following the above steps.